# Process Telemetry from Azure IoT Hub via Azure Event Hub Trigger Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I created an Azure IoT Hub and created a simulated device as well. The simulated Device is working as I used IoT Explorer to validate. I would like to use an Azure Event Hub
Trigger function this time to continuously monitor the data via Azure this time thru logs.

I tried with this function but it does not seem to work. It will only trigger when I manually run it via Code+Test. Can anyone help?

```
public class static ProcessTelemetry{

    [FunctionName("ProcessTelemetry")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "EventHubDefaultConnection")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)

    {

        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (EventData eventData in events)
        {
            try
            {
                // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {eventData.EventBody}");
                await Task.Yield();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

        // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

        if (exceptions.Count > 1)
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

        if (exceptions.Count == 1)
            throw exceptions.Single();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the code you have written does not mention the Eventhub name in the function binding. Currently, it refers to **"messages/events"** (route) instead of the actual Eventhub name. To resolve this issue, it's important to make sure that you have properly configured the connection string for the event hub. If you're utilising the built-in IoT hub feature that is EventHub compatible, then you should use that connection string based on your scenario.

Following the changes, your function code should look like this:

```
public static class ProcessTelemetry
{
    [FunctionName("ProcessTelemetry")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [EventHubTrigger("<EVENTHUB_NAME>", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

        foreach (EventData eventData in events)
        {
            try
            {
                // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array)}");
                await Task.Yield();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                exceptions.Add(e);
            }
        }

        // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

        if (exceptions.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the EventHubTrigger attribute should include the actual name of your Event Hub, and the connection string should reference the correct name of the Event Hub connection string. Also, the method Encoding.UTF8.GetString has been added to get the string representation of the event data body.